# coding with VS Code and but I can't emulate the flutter app in real device (phone)

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

coding with VS Code but i cant  emulate  the flutter app in real device (phone) and icant use  emulator or Android Studio cuz RAM [the syntaxe error on VS Code]

The error is in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Do you have Android Studio/SDK (https://developer.android.com/studio) installed?
If yes, check it out https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21904

Comment: Please don't use screenshot to share code, copy it directly in your question using code block.

Answer (score 0):

First of all did you follow the steps of the official [documentation to install Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows) ? I see on your screenshot that you have not installed Android Studio which you have to even if you don't plan to use the editor.

Once you've installed all tools that you need refer to this [documentation to setup Flutter with VS Code](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor?tab=vscode).

Comment: i can't install android sdk . i did it again and again and i add the path variable .but it can't find the android sdk

Comment: In Android Studio look for "Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK" you will find the location for your SDK which should be something like this: `C:\Users\${username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`